# Parallel.Foreach throws exception InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core-webapi, task-parallel-library, ef-core-2.2

When i am using Parallel.Foreach loop on the collection then it throws exception
"A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however, instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe"

I have onion architecture using .netcore 3.1 and efcore 2.2.
Using Generic repository with unitofwork design pattern

- Created a factory for unitofwork and added a new method
  createFactoryContext.

  `public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory { UnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork(); }`

  ```
   public class UnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
   {
     private readonly YourDbContext _dbContext;

     public UnitOfWorkFactory(YourDbContext dbContext)
     {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
     }

     public UnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork()
     {
        return new UnitOfWork(_dbContext);
     }
   }
  ```

  `
- Registered in startup.cs file

  `services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWorkFactory, UnitOfWorkFactory>();`
- Injected in Service class file Created a object of unitofwork on
  each
  `
  public class MyService
  {
  private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;

  ```
   public YourService(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory)
   {
       _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
   }

   public void SendEmails(UserModel user)
   {
       using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.CreateUnitOfWork())
       {
         Templates emailTemplate;
         if (user.userType = 1)
         {
          emailTemplate = unitOfWork.Templates.GetAllWithNoTracking().Single(x => x.TemplateName= "abc");
         }
         else 
         {
          emailTemplate = unitOfWork.Templates.GetAllWithNoTracking().Single(x => x.TemplateName= "xyz");
         }               
       }
   }
  ```

  }
  `
- Controller Code

  `Parallel.ForEach(result, obj => { _myService.SendEmail(obj);                     });`

What could be the possible solution

Comment: Please have a look into [ask] and improve your question accordingly. As-is, it will probably be closed for lack of information.

Comment: I would argue that error is pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: Clearly you are reusing your context, why you are doing that we have no idea.

Comment: I am reusing this beacuse need to get the template based on user and their respective roles in send email method @Charlieface

Comment: You call a `SendEmail` function but show a `SendEmails` function? The `SendEmails` function is obviously incomplete in that it doesn't use `emailTemplate`.  Is `Templates` thread-safe? Is `GetAllWithNoTracking` thread-safe?

Comment: What is this code trying to do? First, the code loads the *same* object every time, based on a hard-coded template name. Just load it once and reuse it. Second, if you want to load multiple items, write *one* query that loads all of the necessary items instead of trying to execute N queries and definitely don't try to execute them concurrently. Databases are built to return sets of data, not individual rows as if they were files. Executing N 1-row queries won't improve performance, quite the opposite.

Comment: I iterate Sendemails method from controller for user list. Getting template from table based on user type. I updated my SendEmails method. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Not really - there's nothing that sends emails anywhere. It's unclear why you use `Parallel.ForEach` at all, but it's definitely the wrong method. Even assuming you use the least malicious "repository" antipattern, just aliasing DbContext methods, there's no reason at all to load the same templates in separate threads. It's also wasteful to waste threads waiting for IO to complete, which is why `Parallel.ForEach` for IO, database or API calls. Use `async/await` instead, asynchronous operations and at the very least `Parallel.ForEachAsync` *to send the emails*. Load all templates before that

Comment: You can find all user types with `users.Select(u=>u.UserType).Distinct().ToList()`, map them to template names. and *then* load the necessary templates at once. If you have a `Dictionary<int,string>` with the template mapping you can even do that in Select: `var names=users.Select(u=>_userTemplates[u.UserType]).ToList();` and then `var templates=await _context.Templates.Select(t=>names.Contains(t=>t.TemplateName)).ToDictionaryAsync(t=>t.TemplateName,t=>t);`

Comment: Once you have the templates, `Parallel.ForEachAsync` should be used to call already asynchronous methods to send the emails, eg `await Parallel.ForEachAsync(users,(u,ct)=>SendAsync(u,templates,ct));`.

Comment: I will follow the above mentioned approach. Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 2):

Your `UnitOfWorkFactory` should create a new dbContext whenever `CreateUnitOfWork` is called. Something like

```
public class UnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
 {
   private readonly string _connectionString;

   public UnitOfWorkFactory(string connectionString)
   {
      _connectionString= connectionString;
   }

   public UnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWork()
   {
      return new UnitOfWork(new YourDbContext (_connectionString));
   }
 }
```

This way each call to `SendEmails` will use different DbContext objects, and therefore avoid concurrent usage of any context. The framework should pool connections to the database automatically, thus keeping creation of DbContext objects fairly cheap.

However, running database queries in a parallel loop like this is usually not a great idea. If you can, you should usually do as much work as possible work in a single db query, i.e. add a method like `void SendEmails(IEnumerable<UserModel> users)`. Since the example is incomplete and does nothing, it is difficult to provide concrete recommendations.

Comment: Creating DbContext every time is not a good practice. "EF is not thread safe, so you cannot use Parallel."

Comment: @GehanFernando **`DbContext`** is not thread safe. But there is nothing wrong with using different DbContext objects from different threads. If you could only use EF from a single thread it would completely useless for use in a webserver. It might not be a *good idea* to use in a parallel loop, but that depends on the specific use case.

Comment: @GehanFernando Why on earth is it not good practice to create a new DbContext every time? *EF is not thread safe* means you **must** create a new context.

Comment: @GehanFernando quite the opposite, DbContext already is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work and explicitly designed to have limited scope. Disposing a DbContext means discarding any pending changes. A DbSet already is a single-entity repository. Problems like this question's are caused by attempts to wrap the UoW in a CRUD class with a "-Repository" extension.

Comment: @GehanFernando if anything, the question's code doesn't need parallelism at all. It needs *rewriting* so a single query loads all the necessary items. And if the *same* template is used in all calls, it should only be called once and reused